# Why doesn't PyTorch Lightning module save logged val loss? ModelCheckpoint error

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm running an LSTM-based model training on Kaggle. I use Pytorch Lightning and wandb logger for that.

That's my model's class:

```
class Model(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        input_size: int,
        hidden_size: int,
        bidirectional: bool = False,
        lstm_layers: int = 1,
        lstm_dropout: float = 0.4,
        fc_dropout: float = 0.4,
        lr: float = 0.01,
        lr_scheduler_patience: int = 2,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.lr = lr
        self.save_hyperparameters()

        # LSTM
        self.encoder_lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=input_size,
            hidden_size=hidden_size,
            num_layers=lstm_layers,
            bidirectional=bidirectional,
            dropout=lstm_dropout if lstm_layers > 1 else 0,
            batch_first=True,
        )

        # Fully-connected
        num_directions = 2 if bidirectional else 1
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(
                hidden_size * num_directions, hidden_size * num_directions * 2
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(fc_dropout),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size * num_directions * 2, input_size),
        )

        self.loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
        return {
            "optimizer": optimizer,
            "lr_scheduler": {
                "scheduler": torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(
                    optimizer, patience=self.hparams.lr_scheduler_patience
                ),
                "monitor": "val_loss",
            },
        }

    def forward(self, x, prev_state):
        ...

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, _ = self._step(batch)

        self.log("train_loss", loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, embeddings = self._step(batch)

        self.log("val_loss", loss)
        
        return {
            'val_loss': loss,
            'preds': embeddings # this is consumed by my custom callback
        }

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, _ = self._step(batch)

        self.log("test_loss", loss)
```

And that's how I use it:

```
model = Model(
    bidirectional=False,
    lstm_layers=1,
    lstm_dropout=0.4,
    fc_dropout=0.4,
    lr=0.01,
    lr_scheduler_patience=2
)

...

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    monitor="val_loss",
    every_n_train_steps=100,
    verbose=True
)

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    accelerator='gpu',
    precision=16,
    max_epochs=100,
    callbacks=[early_stopping, checkpoint_callback, lr_monitor, custom_callback],
    log_every_n_steps=50,
    logger=wandb_logger,
    auto_lr_find=True,
)

trainer.tune(model, train_dataloaders=train_dataloader, val_dataloaders=val_dataloader)

trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader)
```

When I don't run `trainer.tune(model, train_dataloaders=train_dataloader, val_dataloaders=val_dataloader)` `trainer.fit` works perfectly but when I run 'trainer.tune' I get such ModelCheckpoint error:

```
MisconfigurationException: `ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_loss')` could not find the monitored key in the returned metrics: ['train_loss', 'epoch', 'step']. HINT: Did you call `log('val_loss', value)` in the `LightningModule`?
```

So even though I log `val_loss` it doesn't get saved. On the Trainer object I set `log_every_n_steps=50` and on the ModelCheckpoint I set `every_n_train_steps=100` so it seems that it should have 'val_loss' logged by the moment ModelCheckpoint gets going.

I printed val loss in `validation_step` and it gets computed before ModelCheckpoint is run. I also defined an `on_train_batch_end` function in my custom callback to see saved trainer metrics. It turns out that val loss is in fact missing.

Answer (score 2):

The ModelCheckpoint callback in PyTorch Lightning saves the best model based on a monitored metric, specified by the monitor parameter. In this case, the monitor parameter is set to val_loss, which means the ModelCheckpoint is trying to save the model based on the validation loss. However, the error message is indicating that the val_loss metric is not found in the returned metrics from the LightningModule.

To resolve this error, you need to make sure that the LightningModule is logging the val_loss metric using the log method. For example, in your validation loop, you can log the validation loss like this:

```
def validation_step(self, val_batch, val_batch_idx):
    x, y = val_batch
    pred = self.forward(x)
    loss = self.loss_fn(pred, y)
    self.log('val_loss', loss, prog_bar=True)
    return loss
```

self.loss_fn: is defined by yourself what ever you want to compute the loss of model

Comment: I'm doing exactly that. There seems to be a problem with Tuner.